# VBA unable to fully clear sheet after being called by dropdown + Workbook_SheetChange

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a central summary sheet which is automatically generated using VBA with data from other various other sheets. When the data on other sheets is changed, VBA automatically (using `Workbook_SheetChange`) clears the summary sheet and re-generates it.
For the most part, this seems to work fine, but I've ran into a strange issue whenever I change data via a Data Validation dropdown.

When `Workbook_SheetChange` runs after changing the value in a dropdown, vba seems to be unable to fully clear data from the sheet I'm trying to change.
`.Cells.ClearContents` fails to clear cells, and `.Hyperlinks.Delete` causes vba to stop executing (but links appear to be removed correctly).
Another thing I noticed was that `.Hyperlinks.Count` was only returning correctly if the change was done via the dropdown, any other change would always return 0 (even though it didn't have the other issues listed above).

Not entirely sure if this is intended behaviour or a bug, but it certainly seems strange. At the very least VBA doesn't appear to be throwing any errors.

Is there any way to actually make this work with dropdowns?

I have some example code below which demonstrates this issue:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        Dim TestSheet As Worksheet
        Set TestSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

        With TestSheet
            ' .Cells.Clear 'We don't want to fully clear the sheet.
            .Cells.ClearContents
            '.Cells.ClearFormats 'Sadly this also clears conditional formatting
            .Cells.ClearComments
            .Cells.ClearNotes
            .Cells.ClearOutline

            Debug.Print "TEST1 - " & .Hyperlinks.Count
            .Hyperlinks.Delete
            Debug.Print "TEST2" 'This doesn't run if sheet change is caused by dropdown
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```